# Misunderstanding running bootstrapped t-tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Say that I applied a treatment to some population. I collected a metric before the treatment - let's call that Population A and I collected a metric after the treatment.

I'd like to get a confidence interval over the p-value, but I have two samples here.

Should I compute N bootstrap samples for Population A and Q bootstrap samples for Population B? Then pairwise statistical t-test over all those combinations? Afterwards, I can get a majority vote? Does that make sense?

How do I bootstrap t-test on two populations?

Comment: P-value is not a population parameter, so "a confidence interval over the p-value" is a concept that does not make sense.

Comment: I see many people provide a distribution of viable p-values.

Comment: For example: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10485250902770035?journalCode=gnst20#.VuwvP9UrLnA

Comment: I see. The paper is talking about the confidence interval for a bootstrap-based *estimate* of p-value.

Comment: `The 0.025 and 0.975 percentile values of this collection are a (under friendly circumstances) a 95% confidence interval for the true difference.` Wait - how does that make sense? You can get a p-value by taking the differences in means? Is that a property known by the bootstrap?

Comment: @conjugateprior, is this a well-known approach or did you make it up?

Comment: No I was answering a different question I had thought you'd asked. Disregard.

Comment: Now we need to create (N+Q)*R bootstrap samples (where R is the number of times we repeat the process). I have not heard of this approach before, but it seems very interesting. Do you have any links for this method?

Comment: How do I bootstrap t-test on two populations is answered this way though.  Just compute a t statistic rather than a difference in means statistic. That's the bootstrap sampling distribution of the statistic

Comment: I like this approach a lot. But still a bit weary on whether it is valid. Is there a name for this approach?

Comment: Do you really mean this: "I'd like to get a confidence interval over the p-value"?

Comment: I ask because it's *not* related to "How do I bootstrap t-test on two populations?"

Comment: Would it be possible to bootstrap t-test on two populations, obtain a p-value and a confidence level for that p value?

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea.  (I've also no idea why one would want an interval around a p-value, but that's just me).

Comment: I'd think that we need to have a meta-bootstrap over the bootstrap itself.

Comment: But in any case: For two Gaussians, can I take their difference and take the 0.025th percentile and 0.975th percentile to construct a confidence itnerval? I never knew that.